# TIBCO monitoring docker image

Tags: docker, containers, monitoring, tibco

I read the blog: https://www.rubix.nl/blogs/tibco-monitoring-docker-how-create-instantiate-and-start-tibco-businessworks-container-edition

The blog entry is very interesting. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. My Tibco service does not connect to the monitoring.

Here is some data:

Bwce Version: 2.3
Bwce Mon Version: 2.4

> Log entry from my Tibcoservice: Failed to register with Monitoring
>   application - response code [400] and Reason Phrase [Bad Request]
>
> Log entry from my bwce-mon:
>       INFO:{"host":"172.17.0.4","port":"8090","instanceName":"6866a20e7bd6","appName":"6866a20e7bd6"
>       WARN : Container is not running for (host, port):(172.17.0.4, 8090). Please register running container
>        Docker run command for Tibcoservice: docker run -d -p 7575:7575 --link bwceadmin --name helloworld -e EMS_URL=tcp://ubdev-ws-003:7223 -e EMS_QUEUE=docker.queue -e BW_APP_MONITORING_CONFIG='{"url":"http://bwceadmin:8080"}'
>   helloworld:1.0.0
>        Docker run command for bwce-mon: docker run -p 8080:8080 -e persistence_DB="dockerpostgres" -e
>   DB_URL="postgres://postgres:@172.17.0.2:5432/postgres" -e
>   PERSISTENCE_TYPE=postgres --name bwceadmin bwcemon:2.4.0

Do you have any idea why this did not work for me?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't write the blog post, but I think your issue might be in the configuration of the property "BW_APP_MONITORING_CONFIG".

Can you check if you can access the URL http://bwceadmin:8080? If you can't access that, the issue is most likely to do with the configuration of that property.

To find the setting for that URL, you'll need to know the IP address of the container running your app:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <your container name>
```

After getting the IP address (like 10.100.22.1), you can start a new BWCE app and add a property for the monitoring URL:

```
BW_APP_MONITORING_CONFIG='{"url":"http://10.100.22.1:8080"}'
```